# Using a Laravel factory, how to add different random relationships from a model collection?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-factory

**I'm creating "*Foo*" models using a Laravel 10 factory. I want each model Foo to have a belongsTo relationship to different random already existing model "*Bar*"**. There is no factory for Bar and I want to minimize the number of database queries. For each new Foo, a random Bar should be picked, I don't want to use the same Bar for every Foo.

I found a simple solution but it required to fetch all the Bar models for every created Foo and I wanted to avoid unnecessary queries.

The only way I found is to use states with the Bar models collection :

```
$bars = Bar::all();

Foo::factory()
    ->count(3)
    ->state(function () use ($bars) {
        return ['bar_id' => $bars->random()->id];
    })
```

Isn't there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: `Foo::factory()->count(3)->state(fn() => ['bar_id' => Bar::inRandomOrder()->first()])->create();`

Comment: I'd suggest just setting this up as a state method in the `Foo` factory itself, to be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this issue by generating random `bar_id` values within the factory itself. Here's how you can do it:

```
Foo::factory()
    ->count(3)
    ->create([
        'bar_id' => function () {
            return Bar::inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
        },
    ]);
```